# Asserting the values in JSON response through tests in Postman

Tags: json, postman, assertion

My JSON response body looks like :

```
[
  {
    "_time": "1499996827804",
    "properties": {
      "length": "80",
      "width": "4500"
    }
  }
]
```

I am using Postman to write tests to assert on value of length and width and `_time`.

I wrote :

```
var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);

tests["Check length value"] = data.length === "80";
```

But it's failing. Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your JSON looks like this:

```
[ { "_time": "1499996827804", "properties": { "length": "80", "width": "4500" } } ]
```

Then you need to fix the `data.length === "80"` part of your test.

Firstly, your JSON is an array, so you need to be selecting `data[0]` to get the first item in the response (which is `{ "_time": "1499996827804", "properties": { "length": "80", "width": "4500" } }`). Then, it looks like you're trying to check the `length` part of the response, which is under the `properties` object. So your selector should now look like this: `data[0].properties`.

And finally, to access the `length` part, add `.length` to the end of your selector: `data[0].properties.length`.

Put it all together, and you should have:

```
tests["Check length value"] = data[0].properties.length === "80";
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your data is coming back in an array so you need to get the first item of the array. Also length is a sub property of the "properties" object. Try this:

```
tests["Check length value"] = data[0].properties.length === "80";
```